# How to use systeminfo.exe command lines in a Process?

Tags: c#, windows

I have this code:

```
private void SysInfo32()
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "systeminfo.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "systeminfo.exe>" + "\"" + contentDirectory + "\\systeminfo.txt" + "\"";
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }
```

The contentDirectory is : C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\SF_28-07-13

And i want that the systeminfo.txt will be inside: SF_28-07-13

But the file is never created in this directory.

I used the Arguments the same as i did with the msinfo32.exe and its working with the Msinfo.exe

```
private void MsInfo()
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "msinfo32.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/nfo " + "\"" + contentDirectory + "\\msinfo.nfo" + "\"";
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }
```

So i dont get it why its not working with the systeminfo.exe ?

I used the command line ">" as argument took it from this site:

```
http://www.worldstart.com/generate-a-system-info-text-file/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this

```
private void SysInfo32()
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = contentDirectory;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C systeminfo.exe> sysinfo.txt";
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();
}
```

Why do you still insist to use that ugly syntax for including a directory with spaces when you could easily use the WorkingDirectory property to get the same result is not clear to me